# marquee scroll rotated div in div

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css I need some help. I already have the code of how to rotate a marquee scroll but I want to hide the edges. so basically i want the tiled marquee scroll look inside div thats not tilted, so that the extra marquee scroll animation is not visible

```html
<style>



div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
​
    
}
  
</style>

<div>
    
<marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world

  </marquee>
  
  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world

  </marquee>
  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world

  </marquee>
  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world

  </marquee>
  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world

  </marquee><marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left"> Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world

  </marquee>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To clip your content, you can use a container div and set `overflow:hidden`:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 700px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</marquee>
    <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left">Hello world Hello world Hello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello worldHello world</marquee>
  </div>
</div>
```